# Manually supplying arguments to a MongoDB query to support collation feature (for case insensitive index)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have installed the current development version 3.3.11 in order to test the case insensitive index that is apparently supported according to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90. I have tried this from a mongo shell and a simple test database and it **does** seem to work.

Unfortunately, even though one specifies collation (and strength) during index creation, one must also specify the same collation params with `.find` in order to get case insensitive matches. If collation is omitted from the query, index behaves in a case sensitive fashion.

Even the newest C# MongoDB driver ([2.3.0-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.3.0-beta1)) does not seem to support supplying collation params to a query. So even though I have upgraded the engine and database, C# driver, created the index with required collation, I cannot seem to get the results using the current driver.

Is there a "manual" way of supplying extra arguments to a query?

Comment: Most of the MongoDB drivers will have support for 3.4 out in an RC release by mid-september. If you'd like  a particular collation to be used on a collection in every query/index creation, you can set it as the default collation for the collection. Otherwise, you're going to need to specify the collation to use for every operation you do.

Comment: Thanks so much. You might post is an answer too. Can I modify my collection to support this now that it's holding millions of documents?

Comment: Yes, but your _id index won't change (and cannot) and any indices you have already created will continue to use the collation from when they were created. You can change it using the $collMod operator, although there aren't any docs and I've never done it before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is now possible in the newer version of the C# mongo driver (since 2.4.0).

For example, to query against a case-insensitive index:

```
IMongoCollection<SomeObject> someCollection;
var results = someCollection.Find<SomeObject>(x => x.name == someName,
  new FindOptions() {  Collation = new Collation("en", strength: CollationStrength.Secondary) } )
```

Notice that to enjoy the power of the index, you need to specify in the query the exact same collation parameter as specified when creating the index.

Comment: not working for Turkish collation. Because in Turkish there is a letter İ; dot with I and it is an exception for ASCII table.

Comment: @CanPERK are you sure that the index collation is also tr? İ and i should form a case-insensitive pair. If this does not work in the Primary or Secondary collation strengh for the `tr` locale, a bug should be filed.