# Use of collation in mongodb $regex

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Since v3.4 collations are available for find operations, especially as matches for diacritic characters are concerned. While a find query with a definite value ($eq opeartor or corresponding construct) will match letters and correspondent diacritics, the same is not true if a $regex is used in order to achieve a match on a partial search string (a 'LIKE').

Is there a to make the $regex query use the collation the same way than the $eq query?

consider example collection testcoll:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586b7a0163aff45945462bea"), "city" : "Antwerpen" }, 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586b7a0663aff45945462beb"), "city" : "Antwërpen" }
```

this query will find both records

```
db.testcoll.find({city: 'antwerpen'}).collation({"locale" : "en_US", "strength" : 1});
```

the same query using a regex will not (finds the record with 'Antwerpen' only)

```
db.testcoll.find({city: /antwe/i}).collation({"locale" : "en_US", "strength" : 1});
```

Comment: This not supported at the moment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160072/mongodb-case-insensitive-index-starts-with-performance-problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Case insensitive regular expression queries generally cannot use indexes effectively. The $regex implementation is not collation-aware and is unable to utilize case-insensitive indexes.

Comment: Thx for pointing that out. The problem is therefore yet UNSOLVED :(

Answer (score 6):

I face this same issue today and I searched the Internet like crazy trying to find a solution. Didn't find any. So I came up with my on solution, a little frankenstein that worked for me.

I created a function which removes all the special characters from a string and then replaces all the characters that could be special to the equivalent regexp that could be special. In the end I just add a `"i"` option to cover the capitalize strings in my DB.

```
export const convertStringToRegexp = (text: string) => {
  let regexp = '';
  const textNormalized = text
    .normalize('NFD')
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '') // remove all accents
    .replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&') // remove all regexp reserved char
    .toLowerCase();

  regexp = textNormalized
    .replace(/a/g, '[a,á,à,ä,â,ã]')
    .replace(/e/g, '[e,é,ë,è,ê]')
    .replace(/i/g, '[i,í,ï,ì,î]')
    .replace(/o/g, '[o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô]')
    .replace(/u/g, '[u,ü,ú,ù,û]')
    .replace(/c/g, '[c,ç]')
    .replace(/n/g, '[n,ñ]')
    .replace(/[ªº°]/g, '[ªº°]');
  return new RegExp(regexp, 'i'); // "i" -> ignore case
};
```

And in my `find()` method, I just use this function with `$regex` option, like this:

```
db.testcoll.find({city: {$regex: convertStringToRegexp('twerp')} })

/*
Output:
[
  { "_id" : ObjectId("586b7a0163aff45945462bea"), "city" : "Antwerpen" }, 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("586b7a0663aff45945462beb"), "city" : "Antwërpen" }
]
*/
```

I also create a `.spec.ts` file (using Chai) to test this function. Of course you could adapt to Jest.

```
describe('ConvertStringToRegexp', () => {
  it('should convert all "a" to regexp', () => {
    expect(convertStringToRegexp('TAÁdaáh!')).to.deep.equal(
      /t[a,á,à,ä,â,ã][a,á,à,ä,â,ã]d[a,á,à,ä,â,ã][a,á,à,ä,â,ã]h!/i
    );
  });
  it('should convert all "e" to regexp', () => {
    expect(convertStringToRegexp('MEÉeéh!')).to.deep.equal(
      /m[e,é,ë,è,ê][e,é,ë,è,ê][e,é,ë,è,ê][e,é,ë,è,ê]h!/i
    );
  });
  it('should convert all "i" to regexp', () => {
    expect(convertStringToRegexp('VÍIiishí!')).to.deep.equal(
      /v[i,í,ï,ì,î][i,í,ï,ì,î][i,í,ï,ì,î][i,í,ï,ì,î]sh[i,í,ï,ì,î]!/i
    );
  });
  it('should convert all "o" to regexp', () => {
    expect(convertStringToRegexp('ÓOoóhhhh!!!!')).to.deep.equal(
      /[o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô][o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô][o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô][o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô]hhhh!!!!/i
    );
  });
  it('should convert all "u" to regexp', () => {
    expect(convertStringToRegexp('ÚUhuuúll!')).to.deep.equal(
      /[u,ü,ú,ù,û][u,ü,ú,ù,û]h[u,ü,ú,ù,û][u,ü,ú,ù,û][u,ü,ú,ù,û]ll!/i
    );
  });
  it('should convert all "c" to regexp', () => {
    expect(convertStringToRegexp('Cacacacaca')).to.deep.equal(
      /[c,ç][a,á,à,ä,â,ã][c,ç][a,á,à,ä,â,ã][c,ç][a,á,à,ä,â,ã][c,ç][a,á,à,ä,â,ã][c,ç][a,á,à,ä,â,ã]/i
    );
  });
  it('should remove all special characters', () => {
    expect(
      convertStringToRegexp('hello 123 °º¶§∞¢£™·ª•*!@#$%^WORLD?.')
    ).to.deep.equal(
      /h[e,é,ë,è,ê]ll[o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô] 123 [ªº°][ªº°]¶§∞¢£™·[ªº°]•\*!@#\$%\^w[o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô]rld\?\./i
    );
  });
  it('should accept all regexp reserved characters', () => {
    expect(
      convertStringToRegexp('Olá [-[]{}()*+?.,\\o/^$|#s] Mundo! ')
    ).to.deep.equal(
      /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
      /[o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô]l[a,á,à,ä,â,ã] \[-\[\]\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.,\\[o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô]\/\^\$\|#s\] m[u,ü,ú,ù,û][n,ñ]d[o,ó,ö,ò,õ,ô]! /i
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: You might want to add some tests with commas in them ;) The RegExp character sets will match any character from that set, including the comma. You don't separate the characters in the character set – those are just lists of characters (and character ranges). So yes, your first test RegExp matches `'ÓOoóhhhh!!!!'`, but it would also match `',,,,hhhh!!!!'`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use collation on top of regex. You can functionally implement this behaviour using the correct regex.

Considering to the `Antwerpen` example the following regex gives you all the matches in the database:

`/antw[eë]rpen/i`

To generate the above regex you have to regex-replace your search string first using the following replace formula:

`str.replace(/e/ig, '[eë]')`

And of course you have to do it with all diactric character. Also you can simply use the following library:  [diacritic-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diacritic-regex).