# Compare fullwidth and halfwidth japanese characters in mongodb by using collation and regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, encoding, collation

According to [the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) and [the ICU documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/customization) it should be possible to ignore full-width and half-width difference in Japanese text by utilizing `collation`.

I tried the following;

```
{ locale: "ja", caseLevel:true, strength:1}
```

with different strength but none of them is working.

```
db.getCollection('mycollection')
        .find({"desc":/ﾊﾞﾝﾄﾞ/})
        .collation({ locale: "ja", caseLevel:true, strength:1})
```

This query cannot get result from the following document;

```
{
    "desc": "＊EGRパイプバンド外れ"
}
```

---

***update***

Found reason that in MongoDB regex cannot apply collation, so if I use certain match to perform query the result is perfect:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection')
        .find({"desc":"*EGRﾊﾟｲﾌﾟﾊﾞﾝﾄﾞ外れ???"})
        .collation({ locale: "ja", caseLevel:true, strength:1})
```

This query will return `＊EGRパイプバンド外れ` this result.

But not if I use regex, any suggestion on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make `collate` work with any regex `find` logic, since the regex script will override any `collate` definition, and only use the logic defined within itself, namely find any string that contains half-width `ﾊﾞﾝﾄﾞ` only.

The simplest way to achieve this is to add an extra logic before you send the search text into your MongoDB client, and duplicate the text into both half & full width. You can use some existing tool like [this](https://mariten.github.io/kanatools-java/en/kana-converter/).

Then apply both half & full width search parameters into your `find` condition with `$or`;

```
db.mycollection.find({$or: [{"desc":/ﾊﾞﾝﾄﾞ/}, {"desc":/バンド/}]})
```

Same issue;

- [Use of collation in mongodb $regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441071/use-of-collation-in-mongodb-regex)

Comment: yea I have thought about it, it's my last choice because it cannot handle the mix situation such as `ﾊﾞンド`.

Comment: I have seen some chapters about `normalization` in ICU, and in the demo of ICU http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/nbrowser, seems it's possible use normalization to standardize characters. But I cannot get it work in collation, is it possible to use?

Comment: @Jarvan yeah I've thought about that mixed case, but it is a terrible example, who would send such a mixed text? I've never seen that. But sadly there is no pure mongo solution afaik. You need something before the mongo call... I don't think there is any way to do modification to characters that will make them match both half & full width, especially within regex.

Comment: @Jarvan if you'd like to utilize my solution & also cover the mixed case, you can generate an array of strings, essentially a combination of half & full width chars (like `バﾝﾄﾞ`, `ﾊﾞンﾄﾞ`, `ﾊﾞﾝド`, etc.), and `$or` them all, but that will be really slow in mongo I think.

Comment: you are right it's a bad example. I guess this is the best we can do for now, it's really excessively design for such an unnormal case. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jarvan sorry, I wish I'd have given a full answer, but it is such a weird edge case really :( Please do check my other answers, there are some interesting ones regarding Japanese text :)