# MongoDB match partial text ignoring accents (diacritics)

Tags: laravel, mongodb, diacritics, accent-insensitive

I have two fields that I should match with simple text.

I'm currently using Jenssegers'Laravel Mongodb (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

The code right now is like this, and works almost as like I want:

```
$nameFilter = [[ 
    '$match' => 
    [
        '$or' =>
        [ 
            [ 
                'content.itemList.name' => ['$regex' => new Regex($request->q, 'i')] 
            ],
            [ 
                'content.itemList.commonName' => ['$regex' => new Regex($request->q, 'i')] 
            ]
        ]
    ]
]];
```

What's missing is that I want to ignore accents in the fields `name` and `commonName`, so for example if `content.itemList.name` is **"foöBàr"** and the query is **"obar"** I should get it in the results.

Edit: after days of trying I haven't found a solution yet.

Something so trivial I suppose should be easily done in MongoDB.

Other things I've tried:

- Created a text index for the fields I want to search
- Use collation, which apparently doesn't work with Regex

---

Example documents

```
{
    lastname: "Mbappé",
    firstname: "Kylian",
    name: "Kylian Mbappé"
    otherfields: 123
}
```

What I want:

A query that matches any of lastname, firstname, or name with partial string (lian, appe, mbappe, etc.) both case-insensitive and diacritic (accent) insensitive.

Good matches should be, for example: "Mbappe" "appe" "mbappé" "Kylian" "kylian mbappe"

Comment: If you are using Mongodb Atlas, you could use Atlas Search  autocomplete operator for this.  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/#autocomplete-ref

Comment: I just posted a solution to this problem in this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441071/use-of-collation-in-mongodb-regex/71685820](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441071/use-of-collation-in-mongodb-regex/71685820)

Answer (score 4):

The use of regex with collation is indeed not supported [Use of collation in mongodb $regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441071/use-of-collation-in-mongodb-regex)

I am guessing that in order to make this work, I would to create a workaround such as a field in the MongoDB data without diacritics in order to use it for the search function.

Using your example document

```
{
    lastname: "Mbappé",
    firstname: "Kylian",
    name: "Kylian Mbappé"
    otherfields: 123
    name_clean: "Kylian Mbappe" // this is new
}
```

I would comment on the original post but Stack Overflow says that I need 50 reputation to do that :(

Comment: This was an alternative I thought about, I will implement it if I don't find a more direct solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think try in mongodb like this it will work.

db.users.find({name:{$regex: 'appe',$options:'i'},firstname:{$regex: 'lian',$options:'i'},lastname:{$regex: 'appé',$options:'i'}})