# How to use collation to filter words with accents using Regex

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to get from aggregate using the regex  /alamo/gi, but the data name is 'Don Álamo' . And mongo return nothing.

I've already tried using collation options , but seems no working with regex, without regex its okay.

```
test.partners.aggregate([
    {$match: {'name': '/alamo/gi' }}
    ],{ collation: { locale: "pt", strength: 1 } })
```

without regex i got the result but when im using it not work...

Answer (score 0):

the most efficient way to do case insensitive and accent insensitive searches is to create a text index with default language set to 'none' and do a text search as follows:

```java
db.partners.createIndex(
    {
        "Name": "text"
    },
    {
        "background": false,
        "default_language": "none"
    }
)
```

```java
db.partners.find({
    "$text": {
        "$search": "alamo",
        "$caseSensitive": false
    }
})
```

hope this helps. in case anybody's interested, here's the c# code that generated the above queries.

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Partner : Entity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            DB.Index<Partner>()
              .Key(p => p.Name, KeyType.Text)
              .Option(o => o.DefaultLanguage = "none")
              .Option(o => o.Background = false)
              .Create();

            (new[] {
                new Partner { Name = "Don Álamo"},
            }).Save();

            var result = DB.SearchText<Partner>("alamo");

            Console.WriteLine($"found: {result.Count()}");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, index worked well, but i need this for more fields and text index only works for one field :\...but its a great solution for who needs this in only one field! Thank you

Comment: that's not correct. text index supports multiple keys/fields. mongo [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index) states it clearly. you can index multiple fields in a single text index. the limitation is that there can only be one text index per collection. here's a multiple field [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57000109/4368485).