# Search for field containing case insensitive text in MongoDB C# using collation

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing, collation, case-insensitive

MongoDB [recommends](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-11105?focusedCommentId=1859745&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1859745) using indexes with collation with locale + strength 1 or 2 to search with case insensitive.

This seems to work fine when using an `equals` filter, but not when using a `Contains(text)` filter.

So, for example, if I have a collection of `TDocument` I can create an index like this:

```
//reusing collation to make sure I always use the same
public static class CollationOptions
{
    public static readonly Collation CaseInsensitiveCollation = new Collation("en", strength: CollationStrength.Primary);
}

var indexOptions =
    new CreateIndexOptions
    {
        Collation = CollationOptions.CaseInsensitiveCollation
    };

Expression<Func<TDocument, object>> myIndex = x => x.Name;

var combined = 
    new List<IndexKeysDefinition<TDocument>> 
    {
        // I could combine or have just one
        Builders<TDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending(myIndex);
    }

var indexDefinition = Builders<TDocument>.IndexKeys.Combine(combined);
var createIndexModel = new CreateIndexModel<TDocument>(indexDefinition, indexOptions);
var collection = _magicRetrieverService.GetCollection<TDocument>(); // it's a standard IMongoCollection<TDocument>
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(createIndexModel);
```

Then, when searching like this:

```
Expression<Func<Document, bool>> filter = x => x.Name == "foo";
var findOptions =
    new FindOptions<TDocument,TDocument>
    {
        AllowPartialResults = false,
        //Sort = sortDefinition, // irrelevant
        Limit = 100,
        Collation = CollationOptions.CaseInsensitiveCollation
    };
var queryResult = await collection.FindAsync(filter, findOptions, cancellationToken);
var results = await queryResult.ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Then the query finds all documents that has the name `foo`, `Foo`, `FOO`, `fOO`.

However, If I modify the filter to use `Contains` so that it can also find a document with name `this is FOO also`, the insensitive case search does not work as expected. It only matches the documents with name containing exactly the text: `foo`.

```
Expression<Func<Document, bool>> filter = x => x.Name.Contains("foo");
```

**Why isn't collation in index and find method working as expected and returning all the documents that contain `foo` independently of the case?**

I'm using `MongoDB.Driver 2.12.4` and `mongo:4.0` running as a container

```
docker run --name mongodb -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=dummy -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:4.0
```

Of course, the following filter works fine, but I thought I could deal with case insensitive searches without having to explicitly convert anything.

```
Expression<Func<Document, bool>> filter x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains("foo".ToLower());
```

Related questions but not the same:

[Manually supplying arguments to a MongoDB query to support collation feature (for case insensitive index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145020/manually-supplying-arguments-to-a-mongodb-query-to-support-collation-feature-fo)

[MongoDB and C#: Case insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458950/mongodb-and-c-case-insensitive-search)

Comment: Which MQL operator does Contains map to?

Comment: the linq `Contains` in the c# driver gets translated to `$regex` operator. unfortunately regex operator in mongodb is not collation aware. so, you can't use `Contains` to achieve your requirement.